# Why does scipy.signal.windows.gaussian produce different numbers than Matlab and Octave's gausswin?

Tags: scipy

For example we can use a length 16 window with 3 as the deviation:

```
scipy.signal.windows.gaussian(16,3)
#returns : 
array([0.04393693, 0.09563444, 0.18627046, 0.32465247, 0.50633562,
       0.70664828, 0.8824969 , 0.98620712, 0.98620712, 0.8824969 ,
       0.70664828, 0.50633562, 0.32465247, 0.18627046, 0.09563444,
       0.04393693])
```

Where as octave produces :

```
gausswin(16,3)
#returns : 
0.011109
   0.034047
   0.088922
   0.197899
   0.375311
   0.606531
   0.835270
   0.980199
   0.980199
   0.835270
   0.606531
   0.375311
   0.197899
   0.088922
   0.034047
   0.011109
```

Matlab produces similar results as Octave. I don't really understand why the numbers would be different on purpose? Is it a bug?

Comment: Read to docs carefully.  The use of coefficients is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`gaussian(M, std)`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.signal.windows.gaussian.html) from `scipy.signal.windows` and the Octave function [`gausswin(m, a)`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/gausswin.html) from the Octave `signal` package do not treat the second parameter in the same way.  To translate the Octave parameters `m` and `a` to the `scipy` parameter, you can use

```
std = (m - 1)/(2*a)
```

For example, here's how you can get the same values that you produced in Octave with `gausswin(16, 3)`:

```
In [74]: from scipy.signal.windows import gaussian

In [75]: m = 16

In [76]: a = 3

In [77]: gaussian(m, (m - 1)/(2*a))
Out[77]: 
array([0.011109  , 0.03404745, 0.08892162, 0.1978987 , 0.3753111 ,
       0.60653066, 0.83527021, 0.98019867, 0.98019867, 0.83527021,
       0.60653066, 0.3753111 , 0.1978987 , 0.08892162, 0.03404745,
       0.011109  ])
```